# Duplicate row detected during DML action - Snowflake - Talend

Tags: duplicates, talend, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, upsert

I want to load data into Snowflake with Talend. I used tSnowflakeOutput with Upsert option because I want to insert data if not exists in Snowflake, or update rows if it exists. I used the primary key to identify the rows that already exist.

When I run my job, I have the following error:

> Duplicate row detected during DML action

I am aware that the problem is due to a line that exists in Snowflake, I want to update the line but all I've got is this error.
do you have an idea why?

Please help :)

Comment: Can you share the detailed error or screenshot here? Snowflake has a feature not to load duplicate date for certain duration but not sure how does it work with Talend.

Comment: Is it possible that you do not have a unique record on the key you are using for your MERGE on the source?  Snowflake doesn't like when you try to MERGE into a table where the source has duplicate records.  Try making sure that both your source and target are unique on your key.

Answer (score 14):

The Talend connector might be internally using the MERGE operation of Snowflake. As mentioned by @mike-walton, the error is reported because MERGE does not accept duplicates in the source data. Considering that its an insert or update if exists operation, if multiple source rows join to a target record, the system is not able to decide which source row to use for the operation.

From the [docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html#duplicate-join-behavior)

> When a merge joins a row in the target table against multiple rows in the source, the following join conditions produce nondeterministic results (i.e. the system is unable to determine the source value to use to update or delete the target row)
> A target row is selected to be updated with multiple values (e.g. WHEN MATCHED ... THEN UPDATE)

**Solutions 1**

One option as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#error-on-nondeterministic-merge) can be to set the ERROR_ON_NONDETERMINISTIC_MERGE parameter. This will just pick an arbitrary source row to update from.

**Solutions 2**

Another option is to make it deterministic by using a MERGE query of the following form. This essentially does a de-duplication on the source table and lets you pick one of the duplicates as the preferred one for the update.

```
merge into taget_table t
using (
  select *
  from source_table
  qualify
    row_number() over (
      partition by 
        the_join_key
      order by
        some_ordering_column asc
    ) = 1
) s
on s.the_join_key = t.the_join_key
when matched then update set
  ...
when not matched then insert 
  ...
;
```

Doing this same thing in Talend may just require one to do a dedup operation upstream in the ETL mapping.